# How can I reduce the width and height of a SELECT in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I combine form-control and input-mini to get a SELECT that has a width of about 60px and a height of about 20px?

```
<select id="RoleSelect" class="form-control input-mini { width: 60px; }" runat="server">
```

I created a fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/baileyjames9/c8be067k/2/

Comment: Note that there's a syntax error (the value of class attribute) in your markup. Anyway, you could achieve that by [re-setting the properties](https://jsfiddle.net/hashem/c8be067k/4/) as: `width: 60px; height: 20px; padding: 0px 5px;`

Comment: Yes, or just `padding :0px` instead of `0px 5px;` -> **https://jsfiddle.net/6ebvfnt4/**

Answer (score 1):

You can use style attribute for this, or define css for form-control input-mini in another file.

```
    .form-control.input-mini {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    }
```